# Blender python default function not recognized?

Tags: python, objects, transforms

I'm trying to apply rotation and scale to all objects, but blender apparently doesn't recognize its own functions.

[I've copied this answers code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/apply-transforms-to-linked-objects) and get the following error:
'Object' object has no attribute 'transform_apply'

For such a simple function there seems to be little speak of it, I suppose because no one else is having trouble with it. How do I figure out what's the problem?

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this was an issue with the .blend I was working with. I appended everything to a new blend and then used the code, this time it worked as intended.

Comment: might have worked if you used `selected_objects` instead of `selected_editable_objects`

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that no objects are selected when the operator is run.

The for loop you show should prevent that, so you must have another copy of that (or another) operator call, or you are trying the one line by itself to get the error.

Comment: No, I did have everything selected. I also tried iterating through bpy.data.objects.