# Automatically apply Matrices4x4 transform on Objects

Tags: python, objects, transforms, matrix

I'm working on a reverse-engineering tool, it extracts maps from a game, and the game actually stores the positions of objects instances using Matrices4x4 transformation.

I would like to know how I can apply a transform to an object or to a group of objects. The best would be to make it work with my current code, of course, but in any case I can still rewrite some stuff, doesn't matters.

```py
myMatrix = mathutils.Matrix(
    (0.0, 1.254, 68.14, 0.0),
    (0.01546, 1.254, 204.85468, 0.0),
    (0.45, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    (204.154, 451.943, 345.456, 1.0)
)

name = 0
myCollection = bpy.data.collections.new("Custom Collection")
for i in range(randint(10, 200))
    verts = []  # Just imagine that there's a list of vertices tuple.
    faces = []  # Same, imagine there's a list of faces tuple.
    edges = []  # Empty. Ignore it
    meshdata = bpy.data.meshes.new(f"MyObjData_{str(name)}")
    meshdata.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name=f"MyObj_{str(name)}", object_data=meshdata)
    myCollection.objects.link(obj)
    # How do I set the position of my object using the matrix myMatrix ?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply transforms to linked objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/apply-transforms-to-linked-objects) `meshdata.transform(myMatrix)`

Comment: Some are linked objects and some are basically just objects, does it still work ?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady it's making an error, it says
`meshdata.transform(tie_instance_matrix) TypeError: Mesh.transform(): error with argument 1, "matrix" -  expected sequence items of type float, not Vector`

Comment: Resolved, problem was coming from me